# The effect of Successful Portal Submissions being Removed from an Agent

Tags: achievements, ingress

If you discovered and submitted a Portal, and it got approved and added to the world, you then get x amount of AP, as well as +1 on the progress for the Seer Achievement.

It could be, however, that the Portal is a duplicate of an existing Portal, or it is "invalid", which means other *Agents* are going to flag it for removal.

I want to know the following:

1. **How much AP** do you get **for each successful Portal** submission?
2. If the **Portal gets removed, do you lose the AP** you have gained?
3. If the **Portal gets removed, do you lose the +1 progress** on the achievement?

Also - and this is the main reason I am asking this question - if you do lose AP or achievement progress due to the Portal being removed, and either one of these would make you **no longer meet the minimum requirements** for your current access level, **will you get demoted?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You gain 1000 AP for each portal submission that is accepted (and a key of the portal).
2. You won't lose this AP if portal is removed
3. You won't lose the +1 on the Seer/Pioneer/Explorer stats

And as subsidiary answer, you can't lose neither AP nor badge requirements.

NB:

- for a photo successfully submitted and accepted for a portal, you gain 500 AP.
- for a successfull edit for portal location, title, description you gain 200AP